# Update component A after component B sends callback

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a page component which houses two independent components. When `CompA` invokes a callback to the page I want `CompB` to update. Here's what I have currently:

**MainPage**

```
<CompA OnEvent="@HandleEvent"/>

<CompB Data="@Data"/>

@code {
    public string Data { get; set; }

    public void HandleEvent(string eventData) 
    {
        Data = eventData;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

**CompA**

```
<button @onlcick="() => OnButtonClick()">Click Me</button>

@code {
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> OnEvent { get; set; }

    public async Task OnButtonClick()
    {
        await OnEvent.InvokeAsync("invocation one");

        //...do stuff

        await OnEvent.InvokeAsync("invocation two");
    }
}
```

**CompB**

```
<InputText @bind-Value=@Data"/>
```

When I click `CompA`'s button the page is only re-rendered once with both strings rather than after each event invocation.

How can I make the page and `CompB` update after each event callback invocation?

Comment: Please see the other questions and answers in the duplicate question box.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis The other questions don't actually solve my requirement. I have tried your implementation but it behaves the same as mine. The first event fires but the UI doesn't update; the second event fires and then the UI updates with both event arguments. I would like each event to update the UI.

Comment: If I put a `await Task.Delay(3000)` at `//...do stuff` then both implementations can be seen to actually work.

Comment: See my answer.  I've re-opened the question.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies I gave you a wrong steer.  I missed the `InputText`.

**CompA**

```cs
<button @onclick="OnButtonClick">Click Me</button>

@code {
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> OnEvent { get; set; }

    private async Task OnButtonClick()
    {
        await OnEvent.InvokeAsync("invocation one");
    }
}
```

**CompB**

You need to set up the binding manually here.

```cs
<InputText @bind-Value:get="Value" @bind-Value:set="this.OnValueChanged"/>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string? Value {get; set;}
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string?> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task OnValueChanged(string? value)
    {
        await this.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
    }
}
```

**Home**

Use binding to CompB.  I've added a display to show the current value.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<CompA OnEvent="@HandleEvent" />

<CompB @bind-Value="_data" />

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
<pre>Data: @_data</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private string? _data { get; set; }

    private Task HandleEvent(string eventData)
    {
        _data = eventData;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```